# Animation.jar in java runtime environment

Tags: java

I am using netbeans IDE.I have imported a animation.jar in my project for better gui experience,if i execute it in netbeans,it works fine.But, after i compiled and build the project.I copied the dist folder to desktop and run my project the animation is no longer running please help me,thanks in advance,sorry for bad english.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: When you run your jar on the command line does it throw any exceptions about missing libraries?

Answer (score 0):

this are the errors sir after i convert it to .exe app using launch4j. I bundled it in jre6..in jre1.8 ir latest jre the problem is the my switching icons are not working..

`Executing: C:\Users\syracuse\Desktop\dist\Alumni.exe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: AppPackage/AnimationClass : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at alumni.login.<init>(login.java:28)
    at alumni.Alumni.main(Alumni.java:18)`